# How do I make calendar entries for a Microsoft 365 dynamic group appear in the member's individual calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, exchange

I have a Microsoft 365 dynamic group with a number of calendar items in it. If a member views the group calendar in Outlook they can see the items but this requires them to manually select the calendar. Is there a way to to make these items automatically appear in their individual calendars?

Comment: Are the members authorized access or are they subscribed? ([link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/how-to-show-group-calendar-events-on-everyone-s-personal/m-p/2507092))

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The group is dynamic and so the members are added automatically based on a rule (their division in this example).

Comment: According to the link this requires the AlwaysSubscribeMembersToCalendarEvents/AutoSubscribeNewMembers flags for the group, applying to new members only.

Comment: As i know, Dynamic distribution groups (DDGs) are mail-enabled Active Directory group objects that are created to expedite the mass sending of email messages and other information within a Microsoft Exchange organization. There's no calendar for it. Are your sure you are using a Dynamic group?

Comment: How are you doing with this issue? Is there anything you would like to update?